# Dúvida sobre concatenação na linguagem R

Tags: r

Quero usar essas variáveis que estou importando de uma tabela na minha função,gecode.

A funçao geocode se comporta assim:
       geocode("Av. Paulista, 1578 - Bela Vista, Sao Paulo, Brasil")

queria saber se tem alguma for no R de eu usar variaveis concatenadas como no PHP que uso pontos.

```
   library(ggmap)
    library(leaflet)
    library(readxl)

     # no RStudio o diretorio de trabalho corrente do R aponta para o local
    # aonde o script está
    setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

    # le arquivo excel capitais
    Pontos = read_excel("pontos_turisticos.xlsx")  

    nome = Pontos$Nome;
    bairro = Pontos$Bairro;
    endereco = Pontos$Endereço;
    cidade = "Nova Friburgo";
    estado = "RJ";



     geocode("nome[1],bairro[1],endereco[1],cidade,estado");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em R existe uma função chamada **paste()** não sei se é a ideal mas sempre me atendeu.

```
>paste("Eu", "Quero", "Concatenar")
[1] Eu Quero Concatenar
```

Por padrão a função usa espaço em branco para concatenar vetor, Porem você pode usar o parâmetro *collapse*

```
>paste(str, collapse = " ")
[1] Eu Quero Concatenar
```

No seu caso:

```
>paste(c(nome[1], bairro[1]), collapse = " ")
```

ou

```
>str <- c(nome[1], bairro[1])
>paste(str, collapse = " ")
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Neste caso não é o `collapse`, é o `sep`. Tente com `sep = ""`.

Comment: Então entendi errado achei que ele queria concatenar e colocar ponto, ae só colocar o collapse = " . ", que concatena e no luga do espaço coloca "."

Comment: Certo, eu li mal o seu código, se for só `paste(nome[1], bairro[1])` sem a função `c()`, então é com `sep`, mas assim deverá ser `collapse`. Se quiser concatenar vetores inteiros será melhor `paste(nome, bairro)`.

Comment: Sim sem dúvidas. @RuiBarradas

Comment: A paste() foi muito útil no meu caso!